# Não modificar célula para determinado resultado.( Histórico)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Em uma tabela de gerenciamento eu tenho duas colunas uma `Status(Coluna A)` e outra `Estado Anterior status`. Nesta eu quero guardar o mesmo valor que esteja no coluna A, exceto para alguns caso. De modo que ele guarde um histórico do status quando esteé `concluído`

Ex.:

```
 Status                    Estado Anterior Status
 Em contato                Em contato
```

Caso em que ele não muda

```
Status                    Estado Anterior Status
Concluído                 Em contato
```

Ps.: Já procurei vários código, mas não conseguir executa-lo com perfeição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de clicar na planilha que eu estava trabalhando (no canto inferior esquerdo) e selecionar a opção `exibir código` eu coloquei o seguinte código

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Verifica se esta na coluna A'
     If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
     'Verifica se é diferentes desses valores
        If Target.Text <> "Concluído" And Target.Text <> "Cancelado" And Target.Text <> "Pausado" Then
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E") = Target
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Victor, com o código abaixo a célula correspondente da coluna B só receberá o valor atualizado da Coluna A se nela (Coluna A) não constar a palavra "Concluído".

```
Dim i, Linha_inicial, Linha_final, Coluna As Integer 

Linha_inicial = 10 'Linha inicial dos dados a atualizar na Coluna B
Linha_final = 80 'Linha final dos dados a atualizar na Coluna B

Coluna = 1 '(valor para a Coluna A)

For i = Linha_inicial to Linha_final

 'Se a Coluna A não tem a palavra "Concluído"
 If Cells(i, Coluna) <> "Concluído" then

  'a linha i da Coluna B recebe o valor que está na coluna A                                                                        
  Cells(i, Coluna + 1) = Cells(i, Coluna)  'Coluna + 1 é a Coluna B (=2)

 End if

Next i
```

Comment: Fala @Leo. Essa resposta me ajudar, mas no código acima você percorre a tabela para achar uma mudança. Tem como eu fazer isso cada vez que eu modificar uma célula de A ?

Comment: Uma forma direta de resolver é fazer a entrada pelo Vba por meio de um campo, que poderia ser chamado a partir de um ListBox para ser similar à planilha, selecionando a linha abriria um TextBox para digitar o valor da célula. Então, restaria tratar o resultado conforme o valor digitado.

Comment: Outra solução é padronizar as respostas, pelo teu exemplo parece que é o caso, ai um ComboBox resolve, p. Ex. "Aberto", "Em andamento", ..., "Concluído